# Doors scrape on newly installed laminate floor

Tags: doors

I installed new laminate flooring. Now the French doors leading to the outside scrape on the floor on one side of each door. Prior to installing this floor the doors did not scrape. The doors are fairly new so there is no problem with the hinges. I thought of shaving the bottom of the doors but they have door skirts/rubber on the bottom. So...don't want to compromise the seal.
Not sure how to fix this problem?

Comment: What exactly is scraping, the door or the seals?  Seals can usually be adjusted.

Comment: So was the old floor height lower than the laminate? Is the new laminate just on top the old floor? If so you are probably left with moving the seals.

Comment: you can replace the subflooring with a thinner board or raise the door jambs. if that sounds involved, it is. Thus you can try to remove the seals as mentioned, but if you do, replace it with jamb-mounted sealing products or modify the bottom of the door to accept a lower profile trim.

Comment: Can you add a picture of both the whole door and the bottom where it's scraping (preferably at a door position where this happens)?